# C++ "...does not name a type"

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, using

I've been trying to define a class method which uses a return type declared in the class namespace:

```
template<class T, int SIZE>
class SomeList{

public:

    class SomeListIterator{
        //...
    };

    using iterator = SomeListIterator;

    iterator begin() const;

};

template<class T, int SIZE>
iterator SomeList<T,SIZE>::begin() const {
    //...
}
```

When I try to compile the code, I'm getting this error:

```
Building file: ../SomeList.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"SomeList.d" -MT"SomeList.d" -o "SomeList.o" "../SomeList.cpp"
../SomeList.cpp:17:1: error: ‘iterator’ does not name a type
 iterator SomeList<T,SIZE>::begin() const {
 ^
make: *** [SomeList.o] Error 1
```

I Also tried to define the method like this:

```
template<class T, int SIZE>
SomeList::iterator SomeList<T,SIZE>::begin() const {
    //...
}
```

And this:

```
template<class T, int SIZE>
SomeList<T,SIZE>::iterator SomeList<T,SIZE>::begin() const {
    //...
}
```

Result:

```
Building file: ../SomeList.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"SomeList.d" -MT"SomeList.d" -o "SomeList.o" "../SomeList.cpp"
../SomeList.cpp:17:1: error: invalid use of template-name ‘SomeList’ without an argument list
 SomeList::iterator SomeList<T,SIZE>::begin() const {
 ^
make: *** [SomeList.o] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SomeList::iterator SomeList<T,SIZE>::begin() const {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name `iterator` is scoped to your class and it is a dependent name.  In order to use it you need to use the scope operator and the `typename` keyword

```
typename SomeList<T,SIZE>::iterator SomeList<T,SIZE>::begin() const
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5b0103ef90e7d2f)</kbd>

As pointed out in the comment by [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) you can also use the trailing return syntax as

```
auto SomeList<T,SIZE>::begin() const -> iterator {
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25a34c80faa4bb86)</kbd>

Comment: alternatively, you could use trailing return type which was invented for exactly this reason:  `auto SomeList<T,SIZE>::begin() const -> iterator`.  In this form the return type is looked up in the class's scope

Comment: @M.M Thanks for that.  I forgot about that.  I added it into the answer.